# Font problem in PDF Output since updating LyX

Tags: fonts, pdf, lyx, miktex

First time poster, long time reader!

I recently updated `LyX` from version 2.0.4 to 2.0.6. The `LaTeX` compiler is `MikTeX 2.9`, and the default output is `pdflatex`. Since updating `Lyx` though, the output of the PDF is not "as nice" as it used to be, and I've been searching Google and StackExchange for a solution but to no avail!

I'll attach two pictures of the same document, one compiled before the update and one compiled after, the difference in font is quite noticeable.

Here are screen shots of the same document at the same position:

Before Update:

[image]

After Update:

[image]

Before the update it is clear that the fonts were a lot less "blurred".
If you guys need the PDFs I can email them to you for closer inspection. I just can't for the life of me figure out what happened during the update, I made sure the document settings were preserved!

Thanks very much in advance, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: So you only updated LyX, not MikTeX? And the problem is also visible if you zoom in close on the text (and with the same zoom factor, it's different in your screen shots)? You could try using the Latin Modern (font Document --> Settings --> Fonts).

Comment: I regularly check for updates to MiKTeX using Start -> All Programs -> MiKTeX 2.9 -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Update (Admin) and then I update anything as necessary. As of now I have everything updated.
You're right, it looks like the PDF output after the update has bitmap fonts, I zoom in to a 400% level and I can see pixelation as clear as day, which is not visible in the "before" update PDF output. I tried Latin Modern and it's better, but the text now isn't in the same position as before, messing up the pagination. Any ideas to fix the last hurdle?
Thanks very much Torbjørn.

Comment: Can you check if the `cm-super` package is installed? If not, install it, and switch back to Computer Modern. Why the line breaks are different, I do not know, if font size and margins and everything else is equal. (Edit: to make sure people are notified about your comments, write `@<username>`.)

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT.! I finally found the problem after many attempts and trials! Turns out that the default page size after the update was changed to 8.50 x 11.00 in, whereas the previous version's default was 8.27 x 10.69 in (A4). This small change caused the pagination to go off, so I just changed it and it's all perfect now. Just thought I'd put this here so that others who have the same problem can find an easy solution.
Thanks everyone once again for all the help and guidance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Sort of summary of comments:)

The most common reason for getting bitmap fonts in the PDF is that the original Computer Modern font with T1 encoding is bitmapped. It seems that LyX uses this encoding by default, you'll see `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the LaTeX source. To fix this I think it should be enough to install `cm-super`, which is a (enhanced) replacement for the original fonts.

Another option is to use the font called Latin Modern, which is based on Computer Modern, but extended. To use this with LyX, go to Document --> Settings --> Fonts, and choose the Latin Modern fonts for Roman, Sans Serif and Typewriter. You can also set it as document default, to use it in all documents.

The change in line breaks was not caused by a font issue, but by the default paper size somehow changing from A4 to US Letter. This also changes the size of the text area, and hence line breaks.

Why these problems occurred after updating LyX (and MikTeX) I do not know.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this `\usepackage{fourier}`
It helps!